# Can't go to the previous activity

Tags: java, android

In android, there are three activities. I can go to each activity by using next button but when coming back to first activity from second activity by using previous button, it does not responds to the previous button.
My three .java files are
1. MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

2. DisplayMessageActivity.java

   ```
   public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

   Button pre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
   pre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

       }
   });
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

   Button Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
   Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
               startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
           }
       });
   }
   }
   ```
3. ThirdActivity.java

   ```
   public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.third_activity);

   Button previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
   previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent();
           setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
           finish();
       }

       });
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please paste relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in java variables should start from lower case letter, if it is not a constant variable (see [Variables Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)).

To solve your problem you should call `finish()` after `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` in your `DisplayMessageActivity.java`. Also remove second call of `setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message)`.

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Button pre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        pre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish(); //add this

            }
        });
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);//remove this

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);//rename 'Next' to 'next'
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }
        });
     }
  }
```